# Is there a one liner to destructively use `.split(//)` (e.g. turn string into array)?

Tags: ruby

So far I have:

```
my_array = "Foo bar na nas"
my_array.delete!(" ").downcase!
my_array = my_array.split(//).uniq
```

To get:

```
==> ["f", "o", "b", "a", "r", "n", "s"]
```

I can't seem to use `.split!(//)` like `.delete!` or `.downcase!` but I want to do all of this in one step. Is it possible?

Using `my_array.delete!(" ").downcase!.split!(//)` yields "': undefined method 'split!' for nil:NilClass" so I assume `.split!` just doesn't exist.

Comment: You are correct that `split!` does not exist. However, most destructive methods return `nil` so `downcase!.split` == `nil.split`

Comment: It is not coincidence that `split!` does not exist. It logically cannot. Destructive methods modify the receiver, retaining its identity, which means that the receiver and the result have to be in the same class. `split` is a method that takes a string and returns an array; it cannot be a destructive method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use split with a regular expression matching white space or nothing?

```
"Foo bar na nas".downcase.split(/\s*/).uniq
```

This returns

```
["f", "o", "b", "a", "r", "n", "s"]
```

`split!` does not exist because by convention methods with `!` alter the object itself in ruby, and you can not coerce a string into an array because ruby is strongly typed.

Comment: This works great! And it's very clean. Plus I can chang `s*` to `W*` so that it won't include any non-alphas when necessary. Thank you. (would upvote if I had the rep)

Answer (score 3):

No. If you will read [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21) you will get that destructive methods return `nil` when there is nothing to change, so you cannot chain them. If you want to change string to array of it's letters excluding whitespces you should rathe run:

```
my_array = "Foo bar na nas".downcase.gsub(/\W/, '').split(//).uniq
```

There also don't exist destructive method `split!`. Just how can it exist? Ruby is strong-typed language so you cannot change `String` into `Array` because they aren't related.

Comment: Not all destructive methods return `nil`. See `String#delete!`

Comment: Quoting source: "Performs a delete operation in place, returning str, or nil if str was not modified." So if nothing was changed (modified) it return `nil`. As I wrote.

Comment: Ah. Read your answer too fast. Sorry.

Comment: Using this resulted in : `can't convert Regexp into String`

Answer (score 2):

`my_array.downcase.gsub(' ','').chars.uniq`

Answer (score 1):

```
"Foo bar na nas".downcase.split(//).uniq.keep_if { |item| item != " " }
#=> ["f", "o", "b", "a", "r", "n", "s"]

"Foo bar na nas  t  p".downcase.split(//).uniq.keep_if { |item| item != " " }
#=> ["f", "o", "b", "a", "r", "n", "s", "t", "p"]
```